# Can I upload my printer driver to the MAC app store

Tags: macos, printing, backend

I have a printer driver winch i wish to upload on the MAC app store. But the CUPS backend file needs root permission whereas, its mentioned on the MAC app guidelines link:
    Apps that request escalation to root privileges or use setuid attributes will be rejected

I am packaging my entire driver as a dmg. How can we upload the dmg on the MAC app store.

Thanks and Regards,
Aakanksha

Comment: I don't think this is something that fits in the normal mac app store guidelines, but I think that apple should certainly consider accommodating these kinds of distributions in the future.